# Is it possible to edit an svg:image styles in the browser? (using D3)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm using D3 to load existing SVG images onto my SVG.

If I were to create my own elements, I can easily edit their stroke/fill, etc.

However with image elements, I do not seem to be able to edit them. For example something like this:

```
<image height="32" width="32" xlink:href="some.svg" x="10" y="20"></image>
```

Attempting to change its properties with D3 has no effect at all. For example if I add it as such:

```
svg.append('svg:image')
  .attr('height', SYMBOL_SIZE)
  .attr('width', SYMBOL_SIZE)
  .attr('xlink:href', "some.svg")
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('fill', 'blue')
  .style('cursor', 'move')
```

It accepts my x, y, height, width and cursor attrs/styles, but completely ignores the fill/stroke. I also can't add a border.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Here is a working demo to change fill color: http://jsfiddle.net/u6wX2/

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but I am looking to edit an <image> within an <svg>, not a <circle> or anything like that. Or rather I want to know if it is possible. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ZMX7H/1/

Comment: You would need to change this in the DOM of the included SVG.

Comment: yep, figured, but not sure if there's any way to access that SVG's dom from the parent document? Assuming I may have to fetch it with Ajax and edit it before inserting it into my dom?

Comment: Not with an `<image>` no. You'd need to use `<object>` or `<iframe>` if you wanted to access the embedded document's DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by importing the image I needed using `d3.xml()`

This example grabs tux and gives him some nice pink lipstick.

```
  d3.xml "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg", "image/svg+xml", (xml) ->
    importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true)
    svg.node().appendChild(importedNode.cloneNode(true))
    svg.selectAll('#path119').style fill: 'pink', stroke: 'red'
    svg.selectAll('#path120').style fill: 'red', stroke: 'pink'
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM of a document referenced by an `<image>` element is not accessible.  Once the referenced document is rendered at the right scale and position it is basically a bitmap.  Just as if you were referencing a JPEG or PNG.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement

> The result of processing an ‘image’ is always a four-channel RGBA
>   result.

It is the same as when you do the equivalent in HTML. eg:

```
<img src="some.svg"/>
```